# frameset border color

Tags: html, iframe, css, xhtml

i have this code which include frameset. i have tried to set to this frame set border color.

here it is:

```
<html>
<frameset rows="* , *" border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#ffffff">
    <frame src="http://site.com" noresize="true"/>
    <frame src="http://site.com" noresize="true"/>
</frameset><frameset rows="* , *" border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#00ff00">
</html>
```

I have set BORDERCOLOR but that attribute does not have any effect.

how can i set border color between the frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:
 `BORDERCOLOR=green`

Comment: I think that this attribute should go on the label frame

Comment: the <frame> ? i have tried it's not working either , or if you can explain me what you mean..

Comment: Your code it's ok, just increase the border. You know BORDER=5

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<frameset rows="* , *" border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#ff0000">
    <frame src="http://site.com" noresize="true"/>
    <frame src="http://site.com" noresize="true"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

That works for me (see screenshot below)

[image: Frames screenshot]

Please carefully consider why you're using frames in the first place.